# run create_broadcast.py cannot find apiclient

Tags: python

When I run `create_broadcast.py`, the below error message is obtained.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_broadcast.py", line 7, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named 'apiclient'
```

Comment: Unclear question, Edit it to make more sense

Comment: It seems that you are trying to import apiclient, but it seems to be not found. Provide some code to help you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `google-api-python-client` Write below command in terminal

```
pip install --force-reinstall google-api-python-client
```

Hope it will help :)